# Update/Fetch/Sync a JTextField input by user in a class to a JTextField of another class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

public class FormattedName extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/** Creates new form FormattedName */
public FormattedName() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    Formatted = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    NameOpt = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Formatted.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            FormattedActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    NameOpt.setText("Name");
    NameOpt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            NameOptActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(NameOpt)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(Formatted, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(NameOpt)
                .addComponent(Formatted, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void FormattedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void NameOptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Opt option = new Opt();

}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new FormattedName().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextField Formatted;
private javax.swing.JButton NameOpt;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

and another class

public class Opt extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/** Creates new form Opt */
public Opt() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    firstname = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lastname = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    middleName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    first_name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    last_name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    middlename = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    firstname.setText("FirstName");

    lastname.setText("LastName");

    middleName.setText("MiddleName");

    first_name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            first_nameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    last_name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            last_nameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("OK");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(middleName)
                        .addComponent(lastname)
                        .addComponent(firstname))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(first_name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(last_name)
                        .addComponent(middlename))))
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(firstname)
                .addComponent(first_name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lastname)
                .addComponent(last_name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(middleName)
                .addComponent(middlename, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void first_nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void last_nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  String firstname =  first_name.getText();
    String lastname = last_name.getText();
    outputName = firstname + lastname;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Opt().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private String outputName;
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextField first_name;
private javax.swing.JLabel firstname;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField last_name;
private javax.swing.JLabel lastname;
private javax.swing.JLabel middleName;
private javax.swing.JTextField middlename;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

how do i sync the input entered in class Opt textfield  to textfield of class FormattedName w/ or w/o OK button event.

tried using get() but not working.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is called "Binding". Take a look at BBB (http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home) or JGoodies-Binding (http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html); personally I prefer the latter one, but opinions may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter method in Opt that describes the text, something along the lines of

```
public String getFullName(){   
    return first_name.getText() + middelname.getText() + last_name.getText();  
}
```

You can use this in your nameOptActionPerformed()

```
private void nameOptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Opt option = new Opt();
    option.setVisible(true);

}
```

You now have two choices

1. make the Opt class a modal JDialog instead of JFrame or
2. expose the event handling of the ok button to the FormattedName class.

Id personally go with the modal dialog.

Comment: I add the getFullname() method in Opt class and in FormattedName class i add new Opt().getFullName(); under FormattedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt).still not working.

Comment: @reukEN You need to let the user input something there first!  Thats the reason for a modal dialog. i.e. wait for the window to close, then read the input.

Comment: giraffe.i see.nope,i didnt change it to JDialog.i declared a  private var called fullName in Opt then in getFullName(){ fullName = first_name.getText()...... ; return fullname } .in FormattedName, add Formatted.setText(new Opt().getFullName()); n still doesnt work.am i doing smthing wrong here?done this as i read about accessing var from other class.read also about observable n can it be applied here for a simple textoutput?

Comment: @reukEN I suggest you edit your question to make it clear what your goals are.